# The output contain the same result

Tags: php, postman, laravel-10

I write this middleware function and I am sure about the token
but the output is always:

> "You are not authorized to update this product."

and I try drop the database and migrate is again...
This is in the controller:

```
public function update_warehouse(Request $request, Product $product)
{
$loggedInUser = auth()->user();
$productId = $product->id;

if ($loggedInUser->id !== $product->user_id) {
    $message = "You are not authorized to update this product.";
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 0,
        'message' => $message,
    ]);
}

$input = $request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'name_scientific' => 'required',
    'name_trade' => 'required',
    'type' => 'required',
    'company' => 'required',
    'quantity' => 'required',
    'ex_date' => 'required',
    'price' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $message = "There is an error in the inputs.";
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 0,
        'message' => $message,
        'data' => $input,
    ]);
}

$product->name_scientific = $input['name_scientific'];
$product->name_trade = $input['name_trade'];
$product->type = $input['type'];
$product->company = $input['company'];
$product->quantity = $input['quantity'];
$product->ex_date = $input['ex_date'];
$product->price = $input['price'];
$product->save();

$message = "The product has been updated successfully.";
return response()->json([
    'status' => 1,
    'message' => $message,
    'data' => $product
]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `var_dump()` to view the variables you're testing in the`if` statement?

Comment: hi, are u familiar with xdebug?